# Countdown timer per post doesn't loop

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hello I have a code here the shows the countdown of the future post like this `7days 5hrs 3mins 4secs` my problem is when I tried to add this on while loop it only works on the one latest post and  not the other future post. How will I make this to loop. thanks

**JavaScript:**

```
    <script>
        var end = new Date('<?php echo $date;?>');

            var _second = 1000;
            var _minute = _second * 60;
            var _hour = _minute * 60;
            var _day = _hour * 24;
            var timer;

            function showRemaining() {
                var now = new Date();
                var distance = end - now;
                if (distance < 0) {

                    clearInterval(timer);
                    document.querySelector('.countdown').innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                    return;
                }
                var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

                document.querySelector('.countdown').innerHTML = days + 'days ';
                document.querySelector('.countdown').innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
                document.querySelector('.countdown').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
                document.querySelector('.countdown').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
            }

            timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
        </script>
```

**See image for Example:**

[image]

**Update:** I manage to show the countdown timer in each post by using this:

```
 document.querySelector(".countdown<?php echo ++$num1?>").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                        + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
```

the problem now is its returning the same countdown value, how do I make it differrent. thank you

Comment: Where's that loop? As far as I see, you only print `<div class="countdown"></div>` once. Also, your `showRemaining` function cannot handle multiple instances

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @NicoHaase I added an image that shows the output of the while loop for post, as you can see the timer shows only in one row which is the latest post. I want to show a timer on each post. can you help me?

Comment: also what should I do to make it handle multiple instances, I'm new in Javascript i dont have any idea what to do. please help

Comment: use `querSelectorAll` for the `countdown` class than do the for loop for each node and inside the loop use your JS countdown code.

Comment: @VijayHardaha I tried to use `querySelectorAll` but is doesnt work. or did I use it wrong `document.querySelectorAll('.countdown').innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";` can you please help me do ur suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is the best solution but it works for me, I incremented all the class and var on the loop so that it has a function on each incremented classes.

```
 var end<?php echo ++$num3;?> = new Date('<?php echo $date;?>');

            var _second = 1000;
            var _minute = _second * 60;
            var _hour = _minute * 60;
            var _day = _hour * 24;
            var timer;
           

            function showRemaining() {
                var now = new Date();
                var distance = end<?php echo ++$num4;?> - now;
                if (distance < 0) {

                    clearInterval(timer);
                    document.querySelector('.countdown<?php echo ++$num2;?>').innerHTML = 'COMPLETED!';

                    return;
                }
                var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);
                   
                    document.querySelector(".countdown<?php echo ++$num1;?>").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
                        + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
                   
                
            }

            timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```